# How to use custom template during alembic initialization

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

According to the docs, alembic's template can be specified as `alembic init --template pylons ./scripts`. But alembic searches for templates in only one folder in its root (`python_path/lib/python2.7/site-packages/alembic/templates`).

Is there any way to run custom templates? The idea of the question - automatization of project setup e.g. avoiding any handmade changes (like editing `env.py` file).

Answer (score 3):

As I can see in Alembic sources there is no way to customize template directory location. Template directory is gotten by [Config.get_template_directory()](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/alembic/src/aeeb24bbf863c3e95455677c937c9b22160671a4/alembic/config.py?at=master#cl-120) and is used by [list_templates()](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/alembic/src/aeeb24bbf863c3e95455677c937c9b22160671a4/alembic/command.py?at=master#cl-7).

Although you can try to use [monkey patch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch):

```
from alembic.config import Config

def get_template_directory(self):
    return "my/custom/template/directory"

Config.get_template_directory = get_template_directory

# Invoke Alembic code
```

P.S. I wonder why Alembic doesn't use entry points for collecting available templates.